# How to generate random variables following Gaussian distribution in R?

Tags: r, gaussian

I want to generate xi1 which are independent draws from a Gaussian distribution, with mean zero and unit variance in R but I am a little stuck about how to do that.

Comment: Look at the help file `?rnorm`

Answer (score 2):

try `rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)`, where n is the sample size and the mean/sd can be set accordingly

Comment: There is no limitation to the sample size, should I limit to it?

Comment: Is this following Gaussian distribution? I feel like it follows normal distribution?

Comment: large sample sizes are computationally expensive. Normal is a Gaussian distribution. The term "Gaussian" is just used more heavily in physics. I think you need to refresh on stats and r programming.

Comment: @Hack-R Ok cool! Just for clarifying!

Comment: @DataTx Yes your comment and answer are both correct but there are dozens of existing questions with the answer in it. She must have been confused because she did not understand that Gaussian and Normal are the same thing. We need to close this question or have her delete it.

Comment: @Hack-R yes we should probably do that.